# Is there a way to send a response back to fetch after a redirect?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, fetch, google-oauth, single-page-application

I have a SPA using Express, Passport.js, and React. I'm trying to add Sign In With Google using Oauth2. I'm trying to fetch the sign-in route, return the user back to fetch, and then update the redux store with the user. The problem I'm running into is that Oauth redirects to a callback, and I can't send the user back to the original fetch call. The Oauth redirect is taking me out of the SPA flow.

If it's impossible to respond to fetch after a redirect, what would be the best way to send the user to the front-end to update the redux store? Do I need Next.js? Thanks.

Comment: Browsers never expose redirects to frontend JavaScript code. Instead, browsers either transparently follow redirects (if they have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header), or don’t follow them and instead throw an exception (if they don’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header). So if you are trying to call something that’s doing a redirect but doesn’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, then you’re not going to be able to get it to work from frontend JavaScript code but you’ll instead need to make the request from backend server-side code.

Comment: Oauth automatically redirects to a callback uri. The problem I'm trying to figure out is since I'm forced to a different route, I can't res.json() back to the fetch call. The resource object is different. Is there a way to res.json() back to the fetch call after a redirect?

Comment: No, there is no way